# How to purge old data from SVN repository

Tags: svn

How can I create a new Subversion repository from the current one with last 3 months data
and purge/backup the remaining of the data?

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/5335), it shows how to dump the older revisions to an archive location, then create a new repository from what is left.

Answer (score -1):

Re "Is there are any other solution to this problem?"

Is the size slowing SVN down, if not why don't you just get a bigger disk!

Comment: That doesn't address the question and isn't a helpful answer, there are plenty of situations where that's not a straightforward option.